# Start to use Telegram apis

Tags: api, telegram

I wants to learn to use the telegram apis, but I not found a some tutorial which help me to start. I am very lost. Help;

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of Telegram is very poor and outdated.
I suggest using [TLSharp library](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp) written in Visual C#.

Answer (score -1):

This is the first Step you should read it

https://core.telegram.org/api#getting-started

1- Creating an application

2- User authorization

3- And ..... (Continue)


Good Luck !!!

Comment: The problem is that documentation of Telegram API is not sufficient.